# A specified value is not valid. Adding firewall rule with C#

Tags: c#, firewall

I made a little Windows Form Application to create firewall rules by just Drag and droping .exe files and it doesn't work if the .exe file is in

X:\Program Files (x86)... 
or in 
X:\Program files...

part of my code where i think the problem is:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
        //MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileName(item));

        {
            string addToFirewall = "/K netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=" + Path.GetFileName(item) + " dir=out action=block program=" + item;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc2 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc2.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc2.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            proc2.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
            proc2.StartInfo.Arguments = "/env /user:" + "Administrator" + "cmd" + addToFirewall;
            proc2.Start();
            //MessageBox.Show(addToFirewall);
        }

    }
```

For example, a valid CMD command to add/create a firewall rule would be:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="GOM.EXE" dir=out action=block program="C:\Program Files (x86)\GRETECH\GomPlayer\GOM.EXE"
```

and if i drag and drop GOM.exe file and try to create firewall rule i get an error:

A specific value is not valid.
[image: pic]

My first guess is that something is wrong with blank spaces between

Program( )Files and Program( )Files( )(x86)

Comment: "Administrator" + "cmd"   - space between?

Comment: Your problem is that `Program Files` contains a space, so you need to add quotes around it. So change the line to this: `string addToFirewall = "/K netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=" + Path.GetFileName(item) + " dir=out action=block program=\"" + item + "\""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `Program Files` contains a space, so you need to add quotes around it. Change your line to this:

```
string addToFirewall = "/K netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=" + Path.GetFileName(item) + " dir=out action=block program=\"" + item + "\"";
```

Comment: Thank you Icemanind...unfortunately i can't upvote  your answer because i don't have enough reputation points (recently registered)